# How to compare a range of local ip addresses to a public ip address in php?

Tags: php

How can I compare a range of local ip address to public ip address in php?

I would like to compare my IP adddress in Range or not.
If it isn't in range, I want to echo "fail connected"?

Comment: Please define "in rang".

Comment: Please define "in range". What makes one IP "in range" of another? Which "local IP" are you referring to, 127.0.0.1? The IP assigned by your router? The public internet IP of the server?

Comment: Yes IP rang in local LAN compare with public. if not local rang will echo message access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ipRanges = array(
  array( '10.1.1.1' , '10.1.10.255' ) ,
  array( '192.168.12.1' , '192.168.12.16' )
);


$theIP = '10.1.5.5'; # Could be $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] for accessing IP address


$theIPdec = ip2long( $theIP ); # Converts from an IP address to an integer
$inRange = false;
foreach( $ipRanges as $r ){
  if( $theIPdec >= ip2long( $r[0] )
      && $theIPdec <= ip2long( $r[1] ) ){
   # IP is in this range
    $inRange = true;
    break;
  }
}


if( !$inRange ){
 # No Matches to Ranges
  echo 'fail connected';
}
```